# cannot get the relationship data in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

this is my function

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $newproject = Newproject::find($id);
        $data = [

            'name' => $newproject->user->name
        ];

        return $data;
    }
```

newproject model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'user_id' ,'id');
    }
```

it always getting the error

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`user_id` = 1 and `users`.`user_id` is not null limit 1)"
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\larastart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
line: 669
```

please help my to solve my problem please.

Comment: can u post the user and newproject's column?

Comment: Please share your table structure

Comment: I think have more sense that the Newproject belongsTo User, then you will need a user_id column in the newprojects table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem in my model

in user model

```
public function newproject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Newproject::class,'user_id','id');
    }
```

in newproject model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id' , 'user_id');
    }
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Check the relationship [one-to-one reference](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)
The foreign_key `user_id` is in newprojects table, you need to build the relationship like this:

User model:

```php
public function newproject()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Newproject::class,'user_id');
}
```

newproject model:

```php
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this,

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id' ,'user_id');
    }
```

It means `id` of users table match with current model's `user_id` column. And if you have proper naming convention according to laravel then you don't need to pass this extra params.

[Laravel hasOne relation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Hope it helps:)